# Erro NullPointerException na execução do meu programa

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou fazendo uma atividade com o seguinte enunciado:

> Você deverá implementar um relógio digital em Java. Para isso, você
>   deverá criar três classes, a saber: Contador, Relogio e outra classe
>   para testar a execução (aplicativo Java) com o nome TesteRelogio. Nas
>   classes Contador e Relogio deverão constar os métodos modificadores e
>   métodos de acesso para os atributos criados. O resultado da sua
>   execução deverá exibir todos os horários possíveis do relógio,
>   exemplo:
>
> Formato 24 horas
>
> ```
> 00:00
> 00:01
> 00:02
> 00:03
> 00:04
> 00:05
> .
> .
> .
> 23:59
> ```
>
> Formato 12 horas
>
> ```
> 12:00 a.m.
> 00:01 a.m.
> 00:02 a.m.
> .
> .
> .
> 11:54 p.m.
> 11:55 p.m.
> 11:56 p.m.
> 11:57 p.m.
> 11:58 p.m.
> 12:00 a.m.
> ```

Deverá existir uma opção para exibir as horas no formato 12 horas ou 24 horas. Caso seja feita a seleção para exibir no formato de 12 horas, deverá ser exibido a.m. ou p.m. conforme o caso.

Minhas classes são:

```
public class Contador {

    private int contar;

    //Metodo construtor
    public void Contador(){
        this.contar = 0;
    }

    //add 1
    public void contar(){

        this.contar = (contar +1 ) % 100;
    }

    //set
    public void setContar(int num){

        this.contar = num;
    }

    //get
    public int getContar(){

        return this.contar;
    }


}//end of class
```

classe relogio

```
public class Relogio {

    //Campos da classe
    private Contador minutos; 
    private Contador horas;

    //Constrio Objeto a partir da classe relogio relogio usando 2 objetos do tipo contador
    public void Relogio(){

        this.horas = new Contador();
        this.minutos = new Contador();

    }


    //Metodos pra contar horas e minutos.
    public void contarHoras(){

        int limitar;

        this.horas.contar();

        limitar = horas.getContar();

        limitar = ( limitar % 25 );

        this.horas.setContar(limitar); 
    }

    public void contarMinutos(){

        int limitar;

        this.minutos.contar();

        limitar = minutos.getContar();

        limitar = ( limitar % 61 );

        this.minutos.setContar(limitar);
    }


    //Metodos get e set dos campos da classe:

    public void setHoras(int hs){

        this.horas.setContar( hs );

    }//fim do SetHoras

    public int getHoras(){

        return this.horas.getContar();
    }//fim do getHoras

    public void setMinuto(int m){

        this.minutos.setContar( m );

    }//fim do SetMinuto

    public int getMinutos(){

        return this.minutos.getContar();
    }//fim do getMinutos


    //Metodos para printar em formato 12 hs ou em formato 24 hs

    public void metodo12hs(){

        int contador = 0;

        while(contador < 24){

            if(contador <= 12){

                System.out.print(getHoras() + ":" + getMinutos() + "a.m");

            }//end of if(contador <= 12)

            else{

                setHoras(1);//reiniciar o contador
                System.out.print(getHoras() + ":" + getMinutos() + "p.m");

            }//end of else

            contador++;
            contarHoras();
            contarMinutos();

        }//end of while(contador < 24)
    }

    public void metodo24hs(){

        //metodo a ser implementado, quero fazer o metodo12hs funcionar primeiro 


    }



}//fim da Classe Relogio
```

Classe teste relogio

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TesteRelogio {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Relogio rel = new Relogio();

        int op;



        while(true){

            System.out.print("Formato de horas: ");
            op = input.nextInt();

            switch(op){

                case 12: rel.metodo12hs(); break;

                case 24: rel.metodo24hs(); break;               


            }//end of switch(op)


        }//end of while(true)



      //rel.metodo12hs();

    }//end of main method


}//end of class
```

Ao compilar, apos escolher o formato 12 hs tenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ```
>  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at Relogio.getHoras(Relogio.java:55)
>   at Relogio.metodo12hs(Relogio.java:80)
>   at TesteRelogio.main(TesteRelogio.java:22)
> /home/thiago/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
> ```

Já tentei fazer alterações e inicialização de variáveis nos métodos que aparecem na mensagem de erro mas ate agora não encontrei o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu erro está aqui:

```
public void Relogio(){

    this.horas = new Contador();
    this.minutos = new Contador();

}
```

Construtores não possuem especificação de retorno, pois não retornam nada. Ao colocar um retorno, ele deixa de ser um construtor e vira um método qualquer, embora tenha o mesmo nome da classe.

Como o método nunca é chamado, as variáveis dentro dele nunca são iniciadas. Remova esse `void` da assinatura para que o método funcione como construtor, e o código rodará sem estourar este nullpointer.

Leitura recomendada:

- [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/28595)

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Era esse mesmo o problema.A Leitura recomendada foi de grande ajuda tambem.